# Getting ant.design.pro to work with create-react-app-ts - issues with less imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, antd

I'm trying to get ant.design.pro to work with my typescript react app, I have everything working but the less files aren't loading.

They work for regular ant components.

Looking at the ant design pro project they do the following in a plugin.config.js:

```
// Change theme plugin

import MergeLessPlugin from 'antd-pro-merge-less';
import AntDesignThemePlugin from 'antd-pro-theme-webpack-plugin';
import path from 'path';

export default config => {
  // 将所有 less 合并为一个供 themePlugin使用
  const outFile = path.join(__dirname, '../.temp/ant-design-pro.less');
  const stylesDir = path.join(__dirname, '../src/');

  config.plugin('merge-less').use(MergeLessPlugin, [
    {
      stylesDir,
      outFile,
    },
  ]);

  config.plugin('ant-design-theme').use(AntDesignThemePlugin, [
    {
      antDir: path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/antd'),
      stylesDir,
      varFile: path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/antd/lib/style/themes/default.less'),
      mainLessFile: outFile, //     themeVariables: ['@primary-color'],
      indexFileName: 'index.html',
    },
  ]);
};
```

Which I think I need, I'm trying to mimic this in a react-rewired config-overrides.js to no avail as config.plugin is not a function:

```
const MergeLessPlugin = require('antd-pro-merge-less');
const AntDesignThemePlugin = require('antd-pro-theme-webpack-plugin');
const path =require('path');

const webpackplugin = require('./plugin.config');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.plugin('merge-less').use(MergeLessPlugin, [{
        stylesDir,
        outFile,
    }, ]);

    config.plugin('ant-design-theme').use(AntDesignThemePlugin, [{
        antDir: path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/antd'),
        stylesDir,
        varFile: path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/antd/lib/style/themes/default.less'),
        mainLessFile: outFile, //     themeVariables: ['@primary-color'],
        indexFileName: 'index.html',
    }, ]);
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this?